# Amazon Advertising API throws HTTP 401 Unauthorized

Tags: api, amazon-advertising-api

I am trying to generate ads reports

The create report API gives response as

```
{
    "reportId": "amzn1.sdAPI.v1.p44571.6153E22B.2825ae5c-126d-422c-bf10-53d2d601189a",
    "recordType": "campaigns",
    "status": "IN_PROGRESS",
    "statusDetails": "Report is being generated."
}
```

but the get report status API gives UNAUTHORIZED error

```
{
    "code": "UNAUTHORIZED",
    "details": "HTTP 401 Unauthorized",
    "requestId": "6C1XJ33DSF546P3XZSD"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to ensure you’re using a valid access token.

You should also verify correct scope value and clientID in your header.